# track you tube video

Tags: asp.net

I need to track youtube video status.I need to check the video is played till the end or not.After clicking an play button,user has to see the video till the end. Depending upon this i need to issue a certificate to my user. For this task i need to track the status of youtue video. how can i do this in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Youtube Javascript API. Learn more at [YouTube guide for dot net developers](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html). Also see [YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) and especially the section on [event handlers](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#EventHandlers).

Comment: Could you post the details of /how/ it can be done using the API? Then the next person with the same problem can get help.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it for certain, best I imagine you could do is with some Javascript, start an embedded youtube video playing (set it to autoplay and it will start as soon as the page has loaded), then start a timer in Javascript for the same length of time as the video takes to play.

If the time gets to the end, and the user is still on the page, then they might have watched the whole video. In which case you could make a call back to the server (Ajax or to a ashx handler) saying that is is complete. Then redirect the viewer to the certificate page.

You'll never know for certain as they could start teh video running then walk away to make coffee or something. And I doubt Youtube expose this data themselves (ie, did the end of the video play).

Comment: is there any help available in Youtube api?